# The skin modifier is incorrectly applied to the skeleton

Tags: modifiers

I'm new to Blender and I ran into this problem, when I trying to skin my handrail skeleton (a screenshot of the skeleton is attached below)
[image]
But after applying the skin and trying to reduce it(by pressing the keys <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>), a certain part of my handrail becomes much thinner than the rest, even at this stage it is clear that the part that is closer to the top is much smaller than all the others (the screenshot is again below)
[image]

Comment: Please provide a sample dot blend file. It increases chance to obtain answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select vertex and check **Radius** in *Properties* side panel.
Your issue looks differently, probably two vertices (or split).

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: @shalor1k Don't forget to manually award the bounty. Or it will fall into the void... :(

Comment: @JachymMichal Thanks, I didn't know about it

Answer (score 1):

There could be many reasons, without providing the blend file, one can only guess.
One of the reasons that I can think of is that the edge that has no thickness is split from the rest of the mesh (loose edge). If that's the case, the solution is simply to select that edge in edit mode, then click "Mark Root" in Skin modifier.